# VichUploaderBundle collection with easyadmin no db insert

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle, easyadmin

I have problem with multiple upload files with:

-sf 4.4

-easycorp/easyadmin-bundle "^2.3"

-vich/uploader-bundle "^1.8"

My entites

```
class Offer
{
 /**
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Image",  cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="offer_photo",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="file_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     */
    private $images;

 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Image

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var File
     *
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="image", fileNameProperty="filename")
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", length=255)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

}
```

Easyadmin.yaml

```
- { property: 'images', type: 'collection', type_options: { entry_type: 'App\Form\Admin\FileType', by_reference: false}}
```

Finally form ;)

```
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('imageFile', VichFileType::class, [ 'allow_delete' => true ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Image::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Collection form is rendering correctly.
When I debug form, files are attached, but there's not insert into db.
During single upload file everything works fine, I serach similar problem, but most answer are for symfony3

Comment: It seems like you have an error in your Image entity, fileNameProperty option of UploadableField doesn't match or may be you forget to put filename property in your post.

Comment: @WilliamBridge I changed mapping to correct value, it doesn't work with multiple upload, with single upload it works

Comment: Could you try to use easy admin hook (prepersist and/or preupdate) and for an offer you add the corresponding image ?